# Регулярное выражение для букв, цифр и -

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение:

```
let urlRegx = /^[a-z0-9]+[\-]*/;
```

Оно должно соответствовать строкам:

- 'adhfjkhakldf'
- 'adhfjkhakldf-asdfhjkhadsfkh'
- 'dsafasdf98980'

Но когда я проверяю на пробелы возвращается `true`, то есть:

- 'kladjlasjd laksjdlasj'
- 'klsdfjlksadj   asdklfjlsdajfl'
- 'klsadjflkdjsaf '

https://jsfiddle.net/7zr1fbqw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно немного пересмотреть вашу регулярку:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+([\-][a-z0-9]+)*$/
```

Она основана на вашем примере и пропускает повторяющиеся блоки `[a-z0-9]` от 1 до N, разделенные дефисом. Важно обозначить здесь конец строки `$`, что вы забыли сделать.

Посмотреть работу можно здесь: https://regex101.com/r/E9GT4L/1.

Answer (score 1):

В своем регулярном выражении вы не используете знак конца строки $ и вашему регулярному выражению удовлетворяет первая часть строки. Для проверки можете использовать например такое выражение

```
/^[^\W]+[\-]*[^\W]+$/
```